# Oracle function returning invalid parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I am unable to understand why below function throws invalid parameter error for p_id and p_name parameters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DIFF(
link in VARCHAR2,p_id in NUMBER,P_NAME IN varchar2 ) return
VARCHAR2 IS CHECK VARCHAR2(10);

    BEGIN
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
'select case when exists (select COL_ID,COL_NAME,COL_VALUE from
sys.TABLE_COLS@'||link||' where 
( COL_ID,COL_NAME,COL_VALUE) in(select  COL_ID,COL_NAME,COL_VALUE from
TABLE_COLS) AND COL_ID= P_ID AND COL_NAME = P_NAME ) then
  ''SUCCESS'' ELSE ''FAILURE'' END FROM DUAL' into Check;
RETURN CHECK;
END;
```

COL_ID is NUMBER and COL_NAME and COL_VALUE are VARCHAR2

Kindly suggest what am i doing wrong here?

I need one more help.
I need to call this function in a sql where link should be passed using a subquery. Is it possible somehow? And if yes how can it be done?

select link from table_links;

Comment: at a glance, `USING` keyword followed by `INTO check` and colons prior to `p_name` and `p_id` are missing. eg consider using as `'.... and col_id = :p_id_ and col_name = :p_name_  ...' INTO check USING p_id, p_name`

Comment: thanks, this will work. I needed one more tip. If i need to pass a subquery instead of one of the parameters as i need to use this function in a sql, is it possible?

Comment: You're welcome. yes, possible.

Comment: Sorry for the burden but do you mind citing an example? I tried but it throws error.

Comment: please ignore, i'll put the requirement in a different post. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DIFFC
(link IN VARCHAR2, p_id IN NUMBER, p_name IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  check_result VARCHAR2(10);

BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT COL_ID, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE
      FROM sys.TABLE_COLS@'||link||
      ' WHERE (COL_ID = :1 AND COL_NAME = :2 AND COL_VALUE = :3)
      ) THEN ''SUCCESS'' ELSE ''FAILURE'' END FROM DUAL'
    INTO check_result
    USING p_id, p_name, (SELECT COL_VALUE FROM TABLE_COLS WHERE COL_ID = p_id AND COL_NAME = p_name);

  RETURN check_result;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed one more help. I need to use this function in a sql, There link should come from a subquery. Is it possible to use subquery in place of input params?

Comment: something like select link from table_links instead of link.

Comment: added second answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DIFFC
  (link_query IN VARCHAR2, p_id IN NUMBER, p_name IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  check_result VARCHAR2(10);
  link VARCHAR2(100); -- Assuming a reasonable length for the link
BEGIN
  -- Execute the link_query to get the link
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || link_query INTO link;

  -- Use the retrieved link in the dynamic SQL
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    'SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (
      SELECT COL_ID, COL_NAME, COL_VALUE
      FROM sys.TABLE_COLS@'|| link ||
      ' WHERE (COL_ID = :1 AND COL_NAME = :2 AND COL_VALUE = :3)
      ) THEN ''SUCCESS'' ELSE ''FAILURE'' END FROM DUAL'
    INTO check_result
    USING p_id, p_name, (SELECT COL_VALUE FROM TABLE_COLS WHERE COL_ID = p_id AND COL_NAME = p_name);

  RETURN check_result;
END;
```

above should answer your second doubt.
but make sure that 'link_query' retrieves a single varchar2 value

Comment: So even if the subquery has joins this will work? Also in parameter i wil pass the part after select right?

Comment: should not be an issue. yes pass the part after select.

Comment: Thanks, i tried but there's another issue. if i try joining the subquery with the main query table it's throwing error. the parameter is something like : GET_DIFFC ('link from table_links b where a.id=b.id and b.owner=''Admin''',P_ID,P_NAME) --here if i remove b.owner clause it works but doesn't work with b.owner clause saying invalid alias. What could be the reason?

Comment: The b.owner check is essential else it'd return multiple rows.

Comment: can you share the query you are passing?
link from table_links b where a.id=b.id and b.owner=''Admin
i cant see any table with alias a.id

Comment: alias a is the table in outer query. select GET_DIFFC ('link from table_links b where a.id=b.id and b.owner=''Admin''',P_ID,P_NAME)  , db_name from db_table a

Comment: this wont work.  as in your parameter you are not passing db_table 
try below
select GET_DIFFC ('link from table_links b,  db_table a where a.id=b.id and b.owner=''Admin''',P_ID,P_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

Note: **NEVER** create tables in the `SYS` or `SYSTEM` schemas.

---

You can change the `IN` to a `JOIN` and pass the parameters via a `USING` clause (and `CHECK` is a reserved word so you need to pick another name for that identifier):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_DIFF(
  link in VARCHAR2,
  p_id in NUMBER,
  P_NAME IN varchar2
) return VARCHAR2
IS
  v_CHECK VARCHAR2(7);
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select case
                            when exists(
                                   SELECT 1
                                   FROM   sys.TABLE_COLS@'||link||' r
                                          INNER JOIN table_cols l
                                          ON     r.col_id    = l.col_id
                                             AND r.col_name  = l.col_name
                                             AND r.col_value = l.col_value
                                   WHERE  l.COL_ID   = :1
                                   AND    l.COL_NAME = :2
                                 )
                            then ''SUCCESS''
                            ELSE ''FAILURE''
                            END 
                     FROM   DUAL'
  INTO v_Check
  USING p_id, p_name;

  RETURN v_CHECK;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I have one more issue. I need to pass subquery in place of the link parameter. It is something like this"  GET_DIFFC (select link from table_links b where a.id=b.id and b.owner='Admin'),P_ID,P_NAME); If i remove the b.owner check it works but if i add it throws invalid alias column name issue SAYINS IT IS INVALID FOR LOV SQL and to use valid alias names. Alias a is for the main table.

Comment: @Velocity You have not defined the `a` alias. We don't have your tables but something like `GET_DIFF( (SELECT link FROM main_table m INNER JOIN table_links l ON m.id = l.id WHERE l.owner = 'Admin'), p_id, p_name )`

Comment: @Velocity You are missing a bracket `GET_DIFF( (SELECT` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BkDAzRN0)